# How to make an AIO MSDaRT usb/disk

Tags: windows, multi-boot, bootable-media, dart

I know there's an AIO windows installation disks, but is it possible making an AIO MSDaRT disc/usb?

I wanna have a bootable MSDaRT disk to chose from Vista, Win7, or Win8